# How to fix the "duplicate mapping key" error in the SwaggerHub editor?

Tags: openapi, swagger-editor, swaggerhub

When I paste my OpenAPI definition into the SwaggerHub editor, it shows the "duplicate mapping key" error. If I add some spaces, then an indentation error is shown. How to fix these errors?

Here is my OpenAPI YAML code:

```yaml
  paths:
   /widgets/home-page:
   get:
  tags:
    - home Page APIs sfssf
  description: asd
  operationId: getwidgets
  responses:
    '200':
      description: home page catregories widgets
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              format: https://api.inspireuplift.com/api/v1/widgets/home-page
```

[image: "Duplicate mapping key" error in the SwaggerHub editor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indentation errors and structural errors in your OpenAPI YAML. Specifically, there should be just one `paths` section at the root level, with individual paths listed inside it, like so:

```
paths:                  # <-----
  /widgets/home-page:   # <-----
    get:                # <-----
      tags:
        - home Page APIs sfssf
      description: asd
      operationId: getwidgets
      responses:
        '200':
          ...

  /trending-products:   # <-----
    get:                # <-----
      tags:             # <-----
        - ...
      description: ...
      ...
```

Pay attention to the structure and indentation in this example and fix your definition accordingly.

See the [Paths and Operations](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/) guide on swagger.io for more details.

Comment: Helen please tell me how I write path API for this format: /api/v1/products/8000

Comment: Use `/api/v1/products/{productId}` as the path and define `productId` as a [path parameter](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/).

Comment: Helen When trying to do authorization through bearer token, then unauthenticated error shown. Please tell me about this ![Valid XHTML](https://ibb.co/8PH35F2).

Comment: Make sure your API definition includes the `securitySchemes` AND `security` sections. See the [Bearer authentication](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/) example.

Comment: Helen I want results like "[ {"name": 5}, {"asim": 8} ]" and tried this
 requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
         application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                 is_seller:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                     name:
                      type: integer
                     asim:
                      type: integer
and when run this code required results not shown

Comment: Here is the output of the above code:
{
  "is_seller": [
    {
      "name": 0,
      "asim": 0
    }
  ]
}

Helen please tell me how i get the results like : "[ {"name": 5}, {"asim": 8} ]"